# How can i move my button upside as the text is

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I want my `text` and `button` at the top of the screen, but both the elements have a few gaps between, so I added `marginBottom` to my `text` and then that `text` went to the top. But I want that `button` to be at the top so I added `marginBottom` to the `button` too, but now it's not going to the top.

How can I position it to the top? Where is the style issue coming from? Please, explain my mistake as well.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ margin: 16, marginBottom: '80%', backgroundColor: 'black' }}>Hello World</Text>
      <View style={{ marginBottom: '80%' }}>
        <Button title='Click me' />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `alignItems: 'center'` and `justifyContent: 'center'`.
These two properties combined make the contents of `container` be positioned in the center. `alignItems:center` vertically centers the contents, and `justifyContent:center` horizontally centers the contents.

Since `Text` is the upper child element, giving it a `marginBottom` will space it out from the `View` element containing the `Button`. If you compare your screen with and without that `marginBottom` on the `Text` you'll notice that the button also moves slightly to the bottom if you include the `marginBottom` on the `Text`.

So in short, your code is doing exactly what you tell it to do: `container` tries to position all children to its center.

To fix this, you might want to remove the `container:{ alignItems:'center', }` property. This will most likely push all your elements to the top of the container. After that you might simply use `marginTop` on your `Text` element to push the contents down.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! :) i didn't see the container which comes from default rn template my lesson of the day "read each and every code in the script not just the code that you written"

Comment: That's a great reflection @Nilay! If you keep that mindset you're well on your way to learning a lot in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

Change both marginBottom %80 to "auto".

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text
        style={{ margin: 16, marginBottom: "auto", backgroundColor: "white" }}
      >
        Hello World
      </Text>
      <View style={{ marginBottom: "auto" }}>
        <Button title="Click me" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

[image]

Comment: yep! this is also a good example